# Selected payment method in quote not get changed to default when reload the onepagecheckout in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, payment-methods, quote, cash-on-delivery

I am having two payment methods Online payment and COD in Magento 2. But the default one is an online payment. When I reload the page, the online payment option gets selected by default(even if I changed to the COD option before reloading the page). But my problem is when I get the selected payment method from a quote, it showing as COD because of the last selected option. How can I handle this scenario in Magento 2?